# methods in iterables raising exceptions

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a method where it calls a method from another class and raises an exception when it tries for more than a set no of times. The code is something like this.

```
def get_values(value_giver):
    try:
        vals = [i for i in value_giver.get_values()]
        return vals
    except RetriesExhaustedException:
        raise CustomException
```

for a test case I am writing , I have `safe_patch`ed  `value_giver().get_values()` to raise RetriesExhaustedException like this:

```
safe_patch(self, "path_to_func.get_values",Mock(return_value=RetriesExhaustedException))
```

so when I run the test case , I am getting

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

How else can I test that the function raises that exception and the exception is being caught ??

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a stub class to be passed as argument:

```
class ValueGiver():
    def get_values(self):
        raise RetriesExhaustedException
```

Then you can use that in your test:

```
import pytest

def test_raised():
    with pytest.raises(CustomException):
        get_values(ValueGiver())
```

or, with unittest:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_raised(self):
        with self.assertRaises(CustomException):
            get_values(ValueGiver())
```

You could also patch the value_giver object itself if it is known - difficult to say without the actual test code.